# How to Access List's elements in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of lists like : `List<List<int>> a ;`
How can I initialize it like this:

```
<2 1> <3 0> <5 1>
```

I mean the list "a" has three lists that each one has 2 elements 
And then how can i access each element or change the value of them?

Comment: can you please post your List here

Comment: `a` is a list of lists of int. `a[i]` is an `i`-th list of int. `a[i][j]` is a `j`-th int (of `i`-th list). For instance, `a[2][0]` returns the first number in the third list of your `a` which is 5.

Comment: You know how to initialize and fill a `List<int>`? Then you also know how to initialize, fill and access items in a `List<List<int>>`. If not you should tell us what the problem was. If the answer to my first question was _No_, you should read the available documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise your list like this:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() {2, 1 },
    new List<int>() {3, 0 },
    new List<int>() {5, 1 }
};
```

And then you can access each element like this:

```
var x = list[0][1]; // 1
var y = list[1][0]; // 3
```

And you can access each inner list like this:

```
var inner = list[0];// List<int> (2, 1)
```

And you can update the list like this:

```
list[0][1] = 42;
```

or

```
list[0] = new List<int>() { 10, 11 };
```

EDIT: How to initialise the list with 10 lists of 1, 1

```
var list = new List<List<int>>();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    list.Add(new List<int>() {1, 1});
};
```

Comment: Can u please initilize it by loops?forexample each element should be 1

Comment: Unlimited and for inner one 2

Comment: My bad, what I meant was: how many elements do you want to initialise the outer list with?

Comment: If the inner list is ALWAYS 2 then maybe an array would be better `List<int[]>`?

Comment: Yes that's better

Answer (score 0):

he needs a list of 3 lists of 2 elements each.

```
List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>> { new List<int>() { 2, 1 }, new List<int>() { 3, 0 }, new List<int>() { 5, 1 } };
```